# Android Intent.ACTION_SEND sometimes doesn't do anything (no exception)?

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I am using Intent.ACTION_SEND to send an email from my Android app. When installing the app freshly on my phone the following code works like a charm (the "choose email app" overlay is displayed):

```
private void sendEmail(String mailBody, String recipient) {
    try {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , recipient);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My subject");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , mailBody);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
    } 
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }       
    catch (Exception e) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
        String exceptionTrace = sw.toString();
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "An error occurred while trying to send mail: " + exceptionTrace, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

After performing some operations in my app (nothing email related) and then trying to send an email again, the "chose email app" overlay is not shown anymore. There is no exception or error shown and I can't find anything in the log.
Does anyone have an idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Try `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO` instead `Intent.ACTION_SEND`

Comment: I already tried that - unfortunately it makes no difference.

Comment: I feel you should restart ADB and connect device again to check the logs because without the logs it's very hard to find the solution